# transform a dijit select to a select list

Tags: forms, select, dojo

salam,
please is it possible to  remove the dropDown button to my dijit/form/select for being like a select list.
I can't use dijit/form/MultiSelect because I need to work with store object to fill in and manage dynamically my select. 
ps: it's my fisrt question in stackoverflow ^^

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. There is a `multiple` property on the `dijit/form/Select` as well, but that behaves totally different than you want. Normally the `dijit/form/MultiSelect` widget should be used for that, but it isn't store-enabled like you mentioned.

Comment: I recently came across this: http://www.thejekels.com/dojo/cbtree_AMD.html While it's not a Select exactly, perhaps it's something you can use?

Answer (score 0):

Would have written this as a note, but my reputation is not high enough.
It appears your problem was raised 6 years ago, with a fix still pending:
https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/7245

Answer (score 0):

i have many responses ^^ i waited an alert to my mailbox that i have never received! it doesn't matter...
thank you very match for the answers but I can't use a radio buttons or checkbox because i have to reproduce a select option of ArcMap in web GIS application, this is why I need to find a js component to make a select list (chen I select field on the select list it appears on the query area)

ps: i can't post a picture to explane that because I don't have 10 reputation!!!
once again, thank you very match for the answers ^^